# Datatables - Sorting and search doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using jQuery DataTables with Ajax to show data. It shows data but sorting and search doesn't work. When I click in any column to sort data it show "Processing ..." and nothing happens.

This is my code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="flux-col-1" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="body" id="">
            <div class="row">
                    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>Object</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "mails",
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "from" },
                    { "data": "object" },
                    { "data": "created" }
                ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: `"ajax": "mails",` - what is `mails`?

Comment: "When I click in any column to filter data" do you mean sort? Filtering is done from the search bar. If your sorting and filtering is not working, you need to show your server-side code. That is the nature of using the "serverSide" option with a setting of true. All of your sorting, searching, pagination, etc. is done in the server side code. Without that we have no way of knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Try removing `"serverSide": true`. When server-side processing is enabled, sorting, filtering and pagination should be done on the server. It looks that you're not using server-side processing based on your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this and change ur "ajax":"mails", with your URL like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="flux-col-1" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="body" id="">
            <div class="row">
                    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>Object</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('mails/ajax_list_mail')?>",

        "columns": [
                    { "data": "from" },
                    { "data": "object" },
                    { "data": "created" }
                ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```